# prime ng dropdown unable to select the label when the value is set to entire object

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using prime ng drop down

```
 <p-dropdown placeholder="Select" [options]="(subjects | async)!" (onChange)="subjectChanged($event)"></p-dropdown>
```

Below is the code in my component.ts where I am pulling data as follows

```
subjects: Observable<Array<SelectItem>> | undefined;

this.subjects = this.params
      .pipe(
        filter(p => !!p.classId),
        map(p => p.classId ?? ''),
        switchMap(classId => this.sharedService.getSubjects("Test", classId)),
        map(subjects => subjects ? subjects.map(s => ({ label: t.subjectName, value: s })) : [])
 );
```

If I give `value: s.subjectId`  it works but on drop down change I want to get another property subjectMarks. I am able to do that but when I change the selection I am unable to see the `subjectName` selected in the drop down

Comment: Would be great if you could reproduce it in StackBlitz with the provided sample data. While the `t` from `t.subjectName` where it comes from?